# can use variables from doitbackground in onpostexecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a `inner class` of `asynctask` in a class. I defined some `variables` `arrays` in that inner class. In `doitbackground`, i put some values into them.

When i go go `onpostexecute`, i can use them because they are all in same inner class.

So, i dont need to return something for pass? I am really confused. Is that a bad way, should i define all those inside doitbackground?

Because if i have to pass values, i need to define wrapper because i have to pass 4-5 arraylists. They are different types. But now  i can use them and no need return or pass.

I am searching but there is no information about this. In all asyntask examples, they define variables outside of doitbackground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a class with these fields in a doInBackground, and pass this class as a result.
This also allows you to pass null if an error happened.

```
    class DataClass {
        private int someIntData;
        private String someStringData;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, DataClass>() {

        @Override
        protected DataClass doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DataClass data = new DataClass();

            // doing some job

            if (!errorHappened) {
                data.someIntData = 5;
                data.someStringData = "Just an example string";

                return data;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DataClass result) {
            if (result != null) {
                // handle the result
            } else {
                // error happened
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: So defining before doitbackground method is true way? i did not test if they are null but i dont think they are null

Comment: I have added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do it, but think about encapsulation concept

as you know,

**doitbackground** happen in another thread than ui thread

**onpostexecute** happen in ui thread

so there is common pattern that send AsyncTask parameters in Constructor or Execute Argument, by this way, you can make your self sure that Async class can be reused maybe in another application and fully encapsulated.

Comment: So where to define variables, inside doitbackground or outside, at the start of asynctaskclass? i dont have preexecute.